# Can't get the GORM mongodb plugin to save a new record, even with an explicit flush

Tags: grails, mongodb, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

What I know: mongod is running, the database exists, the collection exists, I can do inserts using the mongodb console, and a connection to the mongod instance is made by Grails (i.e. I can query and so on).

Other details: Grails 2.01, mongodb plugin 1.0.0 RC4, hibernate plugin 2.01, mongodb 2.0.3

```
class Node {
    static mapWith = "mongo"

    static constraints = {
    }

    ObjectId id
    Integer someId //someId can be null or just non-existent
    String name
}
```

What doesn't work: I can't insert any data through GORM, even when I explicitly set flush to true.

```
def n = com.company.project.Node(name: "test")
n.save(flush:true)
```

I've also tried this out in the Grails console, but there's no error message. Is there anything I've done wrong?

Comment: Use the save(failOnError:true) to see the error messages. My guess is that someId needs to be nullable in the constraints.

Comment: By default GORM does not allow insert null value into database, but you can turn it off global by putting in Config.groovy: grails.gorm.default.constraints = { '*'(nullable: true) }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to Grails so someone else may or may not correct me. Anyways the issue is that the Mongodb GORM plugin by default doesn't allow null values of any fields that you specify in Mongodb domain classes.

As of now I'm not sure how to override this behavior, but I will update this if I ever figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to make your properties nullable? Something like this:

```
static constraints = 
{
   someId nullable: true
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply - yes I believe I did. I'm not sure it matters but I'm using GORM with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Execute validate() method before save and take a look on the result, most probably there is some constraint error of which you may not know.